# ¿Subir imagen a base de datos? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Estoy bastante verde con PHP y actualmente mi base de datos tiene la dirección de varias imágenes que proviene de la `carpeta/img`.

Quería saber cómo puedo, tanto añadir, como editar la dirección de las imágenes.

Por ejemplo, tengo que añadir un libro, que necesita una imagen, ¿cómo podría añadir la imagen?, y subir la dirección a la base de datos para que esta se muestre.

Mi base de datos solo necesita el nombre del archivo, no necesita la ruta.

Tengo algo así:

```html
<label>Imagen:</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagen" id="imagen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

El nombre lo puedes obtener con la siguiente línea:

```php
$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
```

Comment: Algo así: $img=$_FILES['img']['name'];